# Mockito with local variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a simple method that returns a `String`.

It also creates a local `List`. I want to test the value added to the local `List`.

Here is an example

```
package com.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.test.domain.CustomerVo;

public class ClassImpl {

    public String assignGift(CustomerVo customerVo) {
        List<String> listOfGift = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (customerVo.getName().equals("Joe")) {
            listOfGift.add("ball");
        } else if ((customerVo.getName().equals("Terry"))) {
            listOfGift.add("car");
        } else if (customerVo.getName().equals("Merry")) {
            listOfGift.add("tv");
        }else {
            listOfGift.add("no gift");
        }

        return "dummyString";
    }
}
```

How can I test that when the `customerVo.getName.equals("Terry")`, `car` is added to the local `List`.

Comment: The ArrayList is purely local to the method, it's not added to the CustomerVo, so you can't test anything. It's as if it didn't exist.

Comment: +1 to Frank. The method could be reduced to `return "dummyString";` and still do the same thing, but more efficiently.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response basically that's a dummy method created to ask if we can test local variable.

Comment: @user1999453 you should have stated that clearly in your question.

Comment: my apologies the way i asked the question, so there is no way to test local variable in a unit test?

Comment: The point that is being made is that you SHOULDN'T attempt to test the value of a local variable. Testing of methods should be in regards to the method's effect: return value, exceptions thrown, parameters or class fields modified, other side effects external to the class. If the value of a local variable does not affect one of these, that local variable is useless and should be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't altogether that easy.

You need to use something like [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

With powermock you create create a scenario before then method is called and play it back, this means you can tell the `ArrayList` class constructor to anticipate being called and return a `mock` rather than a real `ArrayList`.

This would allow you to assert on the `mock`.

Something like this ought to work:

```
ArrayList listMock = createMock(ArrayList.class);
expectNew(ArrayList.class).andReturn(listMock);
```

So when your method creates the local `List` powermock will actually return your mock `List`.

More information [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

This sort of mocking is really for unit testing of legacy code that wasn't written to be testable. I would strongly recommend, if you can, rewriting the code so that such complex mocking doesn't need to happen.

Comment: @user1999453 I'd add that testing that way is quite brittle, as it's really dependent on the internal implementation of the method, instead of testing its result or effects. What if you now need to create a second ArrayList? It has a 50% chance of breaking the test.