# How to get local variable using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I want to test the following method

```
public class A {

    public boolean method(String doc, String rank) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setDoc(doc);
        b.setRank(rank);
        otherMethod(b);
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

My goal is to get the local variable `b` and to check if `doc` and `rank` were set up.

```
public final class ATest {
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        a.method("doc", "rank");
        // get variable b and check if it contains doc and rank
    }
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: If you want to test to see whether setDoc or setRank work, you should be testing B, not the method that uses B.

Comment: do you mean you trying to test if setter is working fine ?if so, you don't need to test setter. If you want it anyway, you should be testing the setter method directly in B object  ( independently like you probably did for otherMethod(B b) ).

Comment: I want to test arguments `doc` and `rank` in `method()` to have some values. `doc` and `rank` should not be null.

Comment: You probably want to mock `otherMethod` and inspect it's input parameter.

Comment: Could you share more of your test class? For example, is `otherMethod` private or does it have any other visibility.

Comment: I agree with korolar and Magnilex.
If `otherMethod` has public visibility, you can spy on `a` and verify its input.

Comment: This has been already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506254/mockito-with-local-variables